# Prevent URLs form JavaScript array from Google indexation

Tags: javascript, url, indexing, nofollow

I have some adverts on my site. This adverts are images and not closed in `<a>` tag. I store adverts URLs in JS array `advertisement`. When user clicks on advert the next JS code executed:

```
    $(".jLinkBlank").click(function() {
        var adverId = parseInt($(this).attr('id').substring(5));
        var url = advertisement[adverId];
        window.open(url, '_blank');
    });
```

But as I see Google indexing such URLs in any case. How can I prevent such URLs from Google indexation?

Solutions like `robots.txt` or `<META NAME="ROBOTS" CONTENT="NOINDEX, NOFOLLOW">` are not acceptable, because URLs list is dynamic and I have other URLs on the pages what must be indexed by Google.

Comment: Could you check if these URLs are not available anywhere else? The reason the Google bot has indexed them might be different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to encode your uri in base64 and decode them when adding them to page :

You can use btoa to decode a base 64 string, atob to encode.

```
$(".jLinkBlank").click(function() {
     var adverId = parseInt($(this).attr('id').substring(5));
    var url = btoa(advertisement[adverId];)
    window.open(url, '_blank');
});
```